# How to call Java function from c

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm stuck with this, I need to call a Java Function from c/c++.

In the examples and tutorials i only see a java app calling a c method, and in this same method calling another java method, but what I want to do is to call a java method from any part of the code. This is what I have:

```
static JNIEnv mEnv;
static jclass mClassAndroidActivity;
static mMethodSayHello;
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL JNI_FUNCTION(AndroidActivity_nativeInit)(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, int width, int height)
{
    mEnv = env;
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
    mClassAndroidActivity = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, cls);
    mMethodSayHello = (*env)->GetMethodID (env, mClassAndroidActivity, "SayHello", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
}

//this method is called from a cpp
void nativeSayHello(char* msg)
{
    jstring string = (*mEnv)->NewStringUTF(mEnv, msg);
    (*mEnv)->CallVoidMethod(mEnv, mClassAndroidActivity, mMethodSayHello, string);
}
```

but is always crashing, I've tried without the NewGlobalRef, using mEnv instead of env in the JNI_Function, I've tried getting the method id from the JNI_OnLoad, but always crashes.

This is the log i get:

02-15 18:09:48.520: W/dalvikvm(27904): JNI WARNING: threadid=1 using env from threadid=0

Comment: 'The "best" log that i get said that env from thread 1 was different from thread 0' This is correct, I believe. You should have a different env pointer per Java thread.

Comment: yeah but how can i save the first env pointer so i can used in different threads

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't reuse `JNIEnv` because it is specific to the calling thread. To call (non-static) Java method from the native code, you need something like this:

```
static JavaVM *gJavaVM;
static jobject gCallbackObject = NULL;

JNIEXPORT jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
    gJavaVM = vm;
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL JNI_FUNCTION(AndroidActivity_nativeInit)(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, int width, int height) {
    // ...
    gCallbackObject = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, obj);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL JNI_FUNCTION(AndroidActivity_nativeRelease)(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    (*env)->DeleteGlobalRef(env, gCallbackObject);
    gCallbackObject = NULL;
}

//this method is called from native code
void nativeSayHello(char* msg) {
    int status;
    JNIEnv *env;
    int isAttached = 0;

    if (!gCallbackObject) return;

    if ((status = (*gJavaVM)->GetEnv(gJavaVM, (void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6)) < 0) {
        if ((status = (*gJavaVM)->AttachCurrentThread(gJavaVM, &env, NULL)) < 0) {
            return;
        }
        isAttached = 1;
    }

    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, gCallbackObject);
    if (!cls) {
        if (isAttached) (*gJavaVM)->DetachCurrentThread(gJavaVM);
        return;
    }

    jmethodID method = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "SayHello", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if (!method) {
        if (isAttached) (*gJavaVM)->DetachCurrentThread(gJavaVM);
        return;
    }

    jstring string = (*mEnv)->NewStringUTF(mEnv, msg);
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, gCallbackObject, method, string);

    if (isAttached) (*gJavaVM)->DetachCurrentThread(gJavaVM);
}
```

This code snippet is not tested. To prevent memory leak, don't forget to call `nativeRelease()` method in your Java code when the reference to the object will not needed any more.

See [The Java Native Interface](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html) documentation for more details.